# Помогите подключить box2d

Tags: box2d

Целый день уже мучаюсь.
По инструкции все просто а на самом деле нет.

The Box2D library is easy to build. I recommend adding the source files in the Box2D folder into your build system or project files for your IDE. The Box2D library is portable, so you should not need to configure it for your platform.
Подключаю к Visual studio 2017.

Пишу например следующее:

```
b2Vec vec(0,5);
```

Компилируется успешно. Дальше пишу:

```
b2World world(vec);
```

1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) в функции _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main

Как подключить нормально?Помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Cледующее утверждение из ReadME неверное:

"The Box2D library is easy to build. I recommend adding the source files in the Box2D folder into your build system or project files for your IDE. The Box2D library is portable, so you should not need to configure it for your platform."

.lib и .pdb файлы надо обязательно собирать самому.